# Share post via facebook php sdk version 4.0.9, Graph API v2.0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Using facebook php sdk version 4.0.9 & Graph API v2.0

Here is my application settings for publishing post.[image]

My code is :

```
$requestjojo = new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array('message' => 'testing'));
$responsejojo = $requestjojo->execute();

// get response
$graphObjectjojo = $responsejojo->getGraphObject()->asArray();

// print Graph data
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObjectjojo, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

This is not working for me, I want to know where's the bug.

**Note : I am getting user data(user profile) properly from this sdk.**

Using `echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl(array('publish_stream')).'" target="_top">Login</a>';`

for login button, when login with Facebook, Facebook is not asking me for this extended permission(publish_stream) too.

Comment: What you get back in `$responsejojo`?

Comment: Empty response. Nothing prints.

Comment: Try to rebuild your code first according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi/4.0.0  This example contains an error handler so you are able to see possible error messages.

Comment: Stefan, edited question for login button extended permission. Also checked your suggestion, but still same empty response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, got the answer.

```
The reason is that "publish_stream" is now deprecated; use "publish_actions" instead.
```

From :

[Error (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24632296/error-200-the-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application-to-perform-this-action)

Answer (score 0):

The loginUrl is not build up properly.

```
 $helper->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'publish_stream',
    'redirect_uri' => $your_redirect_uri
 ));
```

Comment: [error_code] => 100,   [error_message] => Invalid Scope.

-> it seems like "scope" is not require, because its already define in function.